# How can I remove Gmail App Dark Mode stylings?

Tags: css, gmail, ios-darkmode

I'm building out an email using mjml and the design is pretty standard and not flexible to change.

In gmail the copy becomes illegible because gmail inverts the white copy to black copy.

I want gmail to keep my intended stylings, is there a method to ensuring gmail doesn't invert anything?

I've tried:

- Applying `!important` to all the elements I require.
- `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {}` but gmail strips media queries.
- `<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light only">` no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Moe

Answer (score 2):

You can do this hack:

```
<style type="text/css">

:root {

Color-scheme: light dark;

supported-color-schemes:light dark;

}

</style>
```

and include dark mode media query in your CSS:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark ) {
    .body {
      background-color: #CCCCCC !important;
    }
h1, h2, h3, td {
      color: #9ea1f9 !important;
       padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}
}
```

That being said, this will only work sometimes. To style against dark mode the best you can do is style your email in a way that won't be affected when dark mode is active.

Until there is a definitive solution (there is nothing for the time being), you either have to accept the idea that dark mode will stay active, or do what you can to style against it.

[Here](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/) is a resource with more info. The world of email is still not caught up with the browser, many styles are still ignored by different clients and most solutions are experimental at best.

Comment: Thank you for that.
I read that article too. All the readings I can find are about working with dark mode, not un-using it hehe. 
I tried your method, doesn't seem to take on Gmail App Dark (iOS 13.4.1) at all. That is the app I'm testing on through litmus. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I wish there was a way as well. If it makes you feel any better, major brands have to deal with this too.  :)

Comment: I can't believe the Gmail app sucks this big. Apple Mail works flawlessly in Dark Mode.